# Python import file from the same directory: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: python, python-3.6

I have the following files. And I want to be able to run `python web\file1.py` in `Mod1`.

```
Mod1
  web
    __init__.py
    file1.py
    file2.py
  __init__.py
```

and in `file1.py`:

```
import web.file2
```

However, when I run the following command in the directory `mod1`:

```
....\Mod1> python .\web\file1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\web\file1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import web.file2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'web'
```

I tried to change the content of `file1.py` to

```
from . import file2
```

and the error become

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Comment: Have you tried just `from web import file2`?

Comment: It also got the error of `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'web'`.

Comment: @napuzba I'm having trouble resolving the issue described, and I don't find your tutorial to provide a resolution. I believe the issue is related to package name resolution in pylance, as if for a package to be imported, and resolution in the interpreter, run as a script. Either way, I'm stuck doing what works, without pylance type hinting, or getting pylance type hints and not being able to run as a script.

Answer (score 2):

As I understood what You want, You want to have file2.py imported in file1.py

If that is correct, all You need to do is type this in file1.py

```
import file2
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: Yes, this works. However, the python language server (pylance) of visual studio code warned `"file2" is not accessed Pylance
Import "file2" could not be resolved Pylance (reportMissingImports)`

Comment: Check this out then...

https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/glnsf4/local_python_imports_not_recognized_unresolved/fs6nylv?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Answer (score 1):

It seem you are trying to import `web/file1`.
Since there is an **init** file at mod1, you should use this in Mod1

```py
import .web.file1 as f1
```

Then this in file2

```py
import .file1 as f1
```